# AWS SNS:How many maximum Registration ID'S/Token ID's can subscribe in AWS SNS?

Tags: amazon-sns

How many maximum Registration ID'S/Token ID's can subscribe in AWS SNS?

How I Track Registration ID's/Token ID's STATUS?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have set up a Registration ID or Token ID, it's more generally called a Platform Endpoint.

The maximum number of subscriptions for a single SNS topic is 12 500 000 ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html)), and each Platform Endpoint counts as one subscriber. You can request an increase to this limit if you need to.

I'm not sure what you mean by tracking their status—there are many attributes that you might consider as 'status'.

- You can list all of the subscriptions for a topic using [ListSubscriptionsByTopic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_ListSubscriptionsByTopic.html). This is also the only way to find out if a specific endpoint is subscribed to a specific topic, unless you have the subscription arn.
- You can find out if a Platform Endpoint is enabled using [GetEndpointAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_GetEndpointAttributes.html).
- You can check on the status of a subscription using [GetSubscriptionAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_GetSubscriptionAttributes.html).